# Is it ok to use "would" for future reference?

Tags: tense, verbs, past-tense, modal-verbs, would-rather

Is the below sentence correct:-

1. we would be using these spices from next time onwards.

Probably, would is used as past tense for will, but if the above sentence is correct, than why are we using it even for the future reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example "would" is only correct as a conditional (following a subjunctive). For example:

*Q: If you were to win the competition, would you be using these spices?*

*A: If we were to win, we would be using these spices from next time onwards.*

So, yes it does refer to the future but the *conditional* future.

Comment: what if I want to notify someone about the new spices I will use from next time onwards. In that case, can I use would?

Comment: @rahul soni - No. If you intend to use the spices unconditionally then you must use "will".  If that seems too blunt, you could say, *"We plan to use these spices ..."* or, if you are asking permission, *"We wish to use these spices ..."* or, *"We would like/prefer to use these spices ..."*.  It depends who you are talking to and why.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very well explained.

Comment: Also, is this correct? Ex- We would require the following information from your end or we'll require the following info.  Or both are correct

Comment: @rahul soni  - Without further context, the answer is exactly the same. Conditional versus non-conditioal.